# Yoneda Lemma for Monoids

Tags: category-theory

I have a question about the red tagged statement in the image below.

[image]

Why the morphisms of right $M$-sets are in bijection with elements of $S$? According to Yoneda we have the bijection between natural trafos $Hom(Hom_{BM^{op}}(-,x), F)$ and $F(x)$. Futhermore there is mentioned above that that every presheaf (here $F$ and $Hom_{BM^{op}}(-,x)$) corresponding to $M$-sets. 
So I conclude that $Hom(Hom_{BM^{op}}(-,x), F) \cong Hom_{M-set}(M, S)$ where $S$ is a $M$-set corresponding to presheaf $F$.

My question is why $S = F(x)$ holds?

Whole article: https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/04/02/the-yoneda-lemma-i/

Comment: If $F$ is a presheaf then $F(x)$ is naturally an $M$-set. Conversely, if $S$ is an $M$-set, there is a presheaf $F$ such that $F(x)= S$, and the natural $M$-action on $F(x)$ is the one on $S$

Comment: Based on your question, you've underlined the wrong part: you need to work through the statement "a presheaf $BM^{op} \to \mathrm{Set}$ is precisely a right $M$-set".

Comment: So do you mean that a presheaf $F$ is a $M$-set or it's image of $x$? I understood that in such way that the presheaf is canonicaly a $M$-set with $M$-action at $F(x)$ defined by $m \to F(m)$ where $F(x)$ would be just the "unmanufactured" set. Or in other words: $F(x)$ is the image of $F$ as $M$-set under forgetful functor. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yoneda is a nice way of phrasing this result, but you should be able to use the definition of a morphism of $M$-sets alone to see that for every element $x\in S$ there is exactly one morphism of $M$-sets that takes the unit of $M$ to $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you understand that the content of the claim that presheaves on $BM$ are "precisely right $M$-actions" is that these are equivalent (isomorphic, even) categories. Let's call the category of presheaves $\widehat{BM}$ and the category of $M$-actions $\mathbf{Mact}$. This means there are functors $F:\widehat{BM}\to\mathbf{Mact}$ and $G:\mathbf{Mact}\to\widehat{BM}$ with $GF\simeq id_{\widehat{BM}}$ and $FG\simeq id_{\mathbf{Mact}}$. It should then be clear, if you understand the construction of $G$ that $GM\simeq \hom(-,*)$, and that $\widehat{BM}(\hom(-,*),GS)\cong\mathbf{Mact}(M,S)$ follows immediately from the equivalence of categories.

The only missing ingredient to make the claim work is that $GS(*)\simeq |S|$ (where I write $|S|$ for the underlying set of the $M$-action S). This doesn't follow (in any way immediately obvious to me) from some generic property like Yoneda or equivalence with presheaves; this is purely a consequence of how $M$-actions have underlying sets, and the construction of $G$. Where $\phi:|S|\times M\to|S|$ is the map that makes the $M$-action on $S$, we *define* $GS$ as the presheaf on $BM$ such that $GS(*)=|S|$ and $GS(m)=s\mapsto\phi(s,m)$. Moreover, given $A\in\widehat{BM}$, we can define $FA$ such that $|FA|=A(*)$ and $\phi_A:A(*)\times M\to A(*)$ is $(x,m)\mapsto A(m)(x)$. I leave it to you to check that these are functorial. From this it should be obvious why an equivalence of the two categories means that $\mathbf{Mact}$ morphisms $M\to S$ correspond to elements of $|S|$ in a Yoneda-like way.